# Переход по якорю с другой страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Якоря на странице с хешами, есть скрипт с которым в адресной строке не появляется хеш. Но это на одной странице. Мне нужно со второй страницы, переходить по ссылкам на первую и скрипт также срабатывал. Сейчас он не работает со второй страницы. Можно его модифицировать, что бы он еще адекватно работал с другой страницы и мотал по хешу.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').bind("click", function(e){
var anchor = $(this);
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top -70
}, 1000);

e.preventDefault();
```

});

есть еще другой скрипт, он работает корректно на обеих страницах, но оставляет хеши в адресной

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body,html').scrollTop(0);
$("#menu").on("click","a", function (event) {
    var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
        top = $(id).offset().top -70; //-70px это у меня приклеиное меню, если подскажите как якоря сдлеать -70px, буду признателен
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
});
var hash = location.hash;
if($(hash).length){
    var top = $(hash).offset().top -70;
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);

}
```

});

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос ?

Comment: @Hikikomori - Либо первый скрипт поправить, что бы он корректно работал, то есть переходишь со страницы 2 на страницу 1(по ссылке например контакты(href="index.html#contacts")) и пролистывал до контактов и без хеша в адресной строке.
Либо второй, в нем нужно только убрать хеш, он работает и листает на всех страницах.

Comment: Если убрать хеш нужно сохранять идентификатор в куках а иначе как браузер поймет куда листать?

Comment: @Анатолий Шевелев - а атрибуты data-.... использую куки или sessionStorage